# JavaxMail - Message get only mail from getFrom()

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have this code

```
Address[] from = message.getFrom();
System.out.println(from[0]);
```

Which prints: `AuthorName <name@domain>` or `name@domain` - depends by the mail.

How I can get just `name@domain` all the time, without `AuthorName`?

Comment: You could try not to use an [`Address`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/Address.html) but rather one of its subclasses, an [`InternetAddress`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html), which distinguishes between the personal name and the actual email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Address is abstract, and the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/Address.html) points to two derived classes, one for news and the other with the not too helpful name `InternetAddress` (guess news wasn't on the internet back then).

In this case you probably get an `InternetAddress`, which has  [getAddress](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#getAddress--) method which seems to do what you want. So cast the returned address to `InternetAddress` and get the email address:

```java
Address[] from = message.getFrom();
InternetAddress ia = (InternetAddress) from[0];
System.out.println(ia.getAddress());
```